# How to upload a new apk to Google Play Console (react-native)

Tags: react-native, apk, google-play-console

My previous keystore was lost and I contacted the Google Support team and generated a new upload key using the command below.

```
keytool -genkeypair -alias upload -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 9125 -keystore keystore.jks
```

Now I have the upload_certificate.pem file and the support team stated that they reset the key  and I need to upload the new version of my application to the Google Play Console.

I have tried to upload once they reset it once before by generating an apk file as mentioned in the tutorial below.

[Generate release mode APK for React-Native project to publish on PlayStore](https://dev.to/zilurrane/generate-release-mode-apk-for-react-native-project-to-publish-on-playstore-5f78)

But it doesn't work. Getting this error. [image: Google Developer Console error] Is there anything that I am doing wrong?

Comment: whats the error ?

Comment: have you tried setting `targetSdkVersion` to 28 and re-attempt the upload?

Comment: @kenmistry Even when I do that I am getting the same error without the target API part.

Comment: it seems like the quickest solution is to set up the application under a new name with the new key. can you go back to your previous commits to locate the keystore?